# Android: Action when button clicked in an onPause application?

Tags: android, onpause

I was wondering if it was possible to trigger an action in an application when it is onPause.

For example: I wan't to change certain data in my application when I click on the volume button when the screen is locked.

I really don't know if it's possible when the application is paused...

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It's definitely possible, but you'd need to execute from a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you will start service before you lock the screen, for example in `onCreate()` method and in service `onStartCommand()` register receiver:

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //your handling of for example volume change
        }
    };
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

`Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED` - is just example of an action that you wanna handle.
And in service's `onDestroy()` method you have to add this:

```
if (mReceiver != null){
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```